# Can't deploy CakePHP CMS to Beanstalk

Tags: cakephp, continuous-integration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, content-management-system

So I have this CMS I was to generate for an existing DB and I did that with Cake, literally mindlessly baked it out and now I've to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk but for some reason I can't get it done.

The official documentation states I should be able to zip the root folder excluding vendors and upload the zip to EB and it should all magically work. Now I'm new to Cake, but I did do the same deployment with Laravel and it was much more than that. I can't seem to find any info regarding what's happening so I turn to you for help.

So when I do follow the instructions and zip the thing and upload it get "Instance deployment failed to install Composer dependencies specified in 'composer.json' in your source bundle" and the deployment fails. So my next step was to use gitlab-ci.yml and I managed to deploy the project to EB, but of course when I go to the link all I see is "An Internal Error Has Occurred." and when I visit the logs I got a bunch of "No such file or directory" errors.

My first wonder was I run cake locally with "bin/cake server", and I'm assuming EB doesn't ? I'm pretty new to Cake and I've never done anything with cake+eb so I'm wondering if anyone has any hints ? Thanks :)

Comment: Are the logs telling you which file or directory doesn't exist?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response, but I was out of town for a few days. I managed to clear these things out. I installed composer myself on the ec2 that's running the whole thing(not optimal given that autoscaling groups might kill this) and it seems to somewhat work now, but I have another issue now where EB deploys my app via "php -S" command which won't really work with cake so I'm looking into how to replace this with "bin/cake server". I've played with ebextensions before but for some reason here they are making my life harder

Comment: I think that `bin/cake server` is meant only as a development tool, not to run in production. For example, it's not optimized the way something like Apache or nginx is.

Comment: hmm makes sense, so in that case I would have to configure my nginx for URL rewriting right? If so why didn't AWS cover that in their documentation...

Comment: Have never used Beanstalk, so I can't really comment on that, but it seems that maybe they're expecting the user to know how to configure the server software for the application they're putting on it. Configuring URL rewriting for nginx on Beanstalk is presumably the same as configuring URL rewriting for nginx on any other platform, so that would be covered by nginx documentation, not Beanstalk.

Comment: It was covered for Laravel when I did it so I don't know, anyhow that should be it, thanks for the assistance :)